# Running Java application in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I created new libgdx project and i want to run desktop application in Android Studio. Is there something to do with run configurations? In Eclipse i can just choose Run as Java Application.

Comment: @JBaruch what do you mean?

Comment: I referred to the now deleted comment by @der_golem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, i did it. Here is the solution https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA#running-your-project

`Run -> Edit Configurations...`, click the plus (`+`) button and select Application.

Set the Name to `Desktop`.

Set the field `Use classpath of module` to `desktop`, then click on the button of the `Main class` field and select the `DesktopLauncher` class.

Set the `Working directory` to your `android/assets/` (or `your_project_path/core/assets/`) folder!

Click `Apply` and then `OK`.

You have now created a run configuration for your desktop project. You can now select the configuration and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the main method (or anywhere in the main class) and select Run.

Comment: Ok, i ran it but it can't load assets. Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: not sure what do you mean. New question with error message, maybe?

Comment: libgdx uses shared assets for desktop and android version, desktop version doesn't see this assets folder